# Pause Flexslider when overlay is open

Tags: jquery, flexslider

We are currently working on a project that utilizes the Flexslider plugin (recently acquired by Woo Themes). We have multiple pop ups on this page and we want the slider to pause when the pop ups are active and resume when the pop ups close. The pause only works the first go 'round and the resuming the slider does not work. Below is the code we are using for the slider. I have tried switching out the "start" function with all available calls except the "end" call.

```
$w('#slider-frame').flexslider({
        animation: 'fade',
        directionNav: false,
        slideshowSpeed: 4000,
        controlNav: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        manualControls: '#indicator-dots li',
        start: function(slider){

            $w('.roi-click').click(function(){
                slider.trigger('mouseenter');
            });

            $w('div#ovrly, a#close').click(function(){
                slider.trigger('mouseleave');
            });

        }
    });
```

The link to the page is http://www.whitehardt.com/sandbox/whitehardt-v3.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited**

I think I figured out what's going on here.  The problem is you have conflicting events going on.

1. Flexslider starts the animation by doing `setInterval` and storing the interval ID in an internal state variable (`slider.animatedSlides`).
2. Flexslider pauses when you hover over the slide.  It does this by clearing the animation interval with `clearInterval()`.
3. You click the `roi` link in the slide, which pauses again, by clearing what is now a non-existant interval.
4. The page has an overlay on it, which means you do a `mouseleave` on the Flexslider, so it starts the animation up again with `setInterval()` and stores the interval ID.
5. You close the overlay, by clicking the close button or the overlay, at which point you call `resume()`, which also does a `setInterval()`, overwriting the stored interval ID. So, **now you have two animations going**, hence the double speed.  **Plus,** next time you call `pause()`, it only has access to clear the last interval you set because it overwrote the stored ID.  So, you can no longer clear the interval from step 3.  So, you will be going between having a one interval animation going (slow), when you `mouseenter` and two when you `mouseleave` (fast).

Instead of pausing on the click, you could pause on `#ovrly` mouseover, and resume on click, because the mouseexit of the Flexslider would before the mouseover of the overlay.

```
$w('#slider-frame').flexslider({
    animation: 'fade',
    directionNav: false,
    slideshowSpeed: 4000,
    controlNav: true,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    manualControls: '#indicator-dots li',
    start: function(slider){
        $w('div#ovrly').mouseover(function(){
            slider.pause();
        });
        $w('div#ovrly, a#close').click(function() {
            slider.resume();
        });
    }
});
```

**But**, you may run into similar problems, depending on whether the mouse is over the slider or not when the overlay is closed... but I'm not sure.  Ideally, Flexslider wouldn't start a new animation if one was already going.  You could hack this into flexslider.js:

```
//FlexSlider: Automatic Slideshow Pause
slider.pause = function() {
  // Only pause if running
  if(slider.animatedSlides == null) {
      return;
  }

  clearInterval(slider.animatedSlides);

  // Clear the interval ID
  slider.animatedSlides = null;

  if (slider.vars.pausePlay) {
    slider.pausePlay.removeClass('pause').addClass('play').text(slider.vars.playText);
  }
}

//FlexSlider: Automatic Slideshow Start/Resume
slider.resume = function() {
  // Only resume if paused
  if(slider.animatedSlides != null) {
      return;
  }
  slider.animatedSlides = setInterval(slider.animateSlides, slider.vars.slideshowSpeed);
  if (slider.vars.pausePlay) {
    slider.pausePlay.removeClass('play').addClass('pause').text(slider.vars.pauseText);
  }
}
```

You could overload these functions in your `start:` parameter function.

This change will solve the fast speed and the fact that you can't pause again.  You will still have the problem of the slider resuming when your overlay pops up.  This can be solved with the `mouseover` solution I mentioned before.

Here is a fiddle that shows the `mouseover` solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/TWN5t/

It looks as if you may not need the second hack, although it is better code.

Comment: This works to pause it but once resumed it cuts the duration of the slides in half. Also it will only pause the slider the first time. Additional opening of the pop ups will not pause it and when the pop up is closed the slides move faster.

Comment: Try my edits above.  I think your slider is out of scope in the click handler.  Make a global variable to hold a reference to slider, and then use it in your click handlers.  See if that changes anything.

Comment: This is a great solution but unfortunately after opening and closing it a few times it glitches out. This is only a concern since there are multiple places to click to this video pop up and it is likely that our audience will click multiple times. I tried some variations of your code but to no avail. I really like triggering the pause on mouseover of our overlay. We also have a full site wrapper (#full-wrap), I tried triggering the play on mouseover of this element but it caused a glitch as well.

Comment: Thanks for the work you have put into this. It is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, triggering play on the full wrap would definitely glitch unless you implement the slider hack/fix I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you!!! The problem is fixed after implementing the hack/fix. WooThemes should consider adding this to the FlexSlider! I would have voted the answer up but am too new to Stack Overflow to do so.

Answer (score 1):

@Jeff B, thanks for the JS fix. Since it doesn't work with the 2.x branch of Flexslider I think it's just for 1.x

For those on 2.x, a fix has been submitted by nvartolomei:
https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/pull/322

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Perhaps did you find a way to get the current slider state? Something like "isStopped" or "isPlaying" should be really useful if you want to stop/play by click.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue working with brightcove+flexslider.
here is my workaround:

before

```
        pausePlay: true,
        pauseText :"Pause",
        playText  :"Play"
```

then

```
video.addEventListener(BCMediaEvent.PLAY, function () {
    $('.flex-pauseplay .flex-pause').trigger('click');
});

video.addEventListener(BCMediaEvent.STOP, function () {
    $('.flex-pauseplay .flex-play').trigger('click');   
});
```

.flex-pauseplay .flex-play css opacity: 0