# Pause FlexSlider when PrettyPhoto is open

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto, flexslider

Following on from this discussion:

[Pause Flexslider when overlay is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608844/pause-flexslider-when-overlay-is-open)

PrettyPhoto overlay is called div.pp_overlay but when I amend the code to account for this it ignores it.

```
    start: function(slider) {
        $('div.pp_overlay').hover(function() {
            slider.pause();
        });

        $('div.pp_overlay').click( function() {
            slider.resume();
        });
    }
});
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to call that function inside

```
jQuery(document).ready(function{

*/Here goes the function/*

});
```

or

```
jQuery(window).load(function{

*/Here goes the function/*

});
```

Best Regards.