# How do I stop the slide animation in FlexSlider?

Tags: jquery, animation, slideshow

I'm have a three-slide slideshow going on with FlexSlider, and I'm trying to programmatically make it pause and resume. How do I do that?

Basically, I'm trying to make it stop when the user makes a modal pop up, so the stop is going to go inside a .click() function.

Comment: Could you post some code to demonstrate what you've tried so far?

Comment: I don't even know what code TO try. The docs aren't very clear. There's no "TO stop the animation, do this; to restart, do this."

Comment: Ok. But are you currently able to somehow start the animation? What does that code look like?

Comment: The animation starts automatically. The code:

    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        pauseOnAction: false,
        slideshowSpeed: 3000
    });

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is how to stop it via an included script.

Comment: I think this question has already been asked (and answered): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849075/how-do-i-stop-auto-sliding-in-my-flexslider.

Comment: Nope. All that does is freeze it by default.

Comment: [THIS is what I was looking for! I need to use better search terms!][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608844/pause-flexslider-when-overlay-is-open

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `pause()` on the flexslider jQuery object, like:

```
var mySlider =  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    pauseOnAction: false,
    slideshowSpeed: 3000
});

$('#pause_button').on('click.forMySlider'
    ,function(){ mySlider.pause(); });
```

Taken from the developer website for [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/).

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. The script is coming from another file and thinks "mySlider" is undefined. And if as an experiment I move the click event into the same script (which is not possible when the site is live), I'm told "mySlider.pause is not a function." And in fact, copying and pasting your code into there gives me the aforementioned "not a function" problem.